# nested sj:tabbedpanel redirection after form submission using struts2

Tags: jquery-ui, struts2

I have a form in a nested sj:tabbedpanel and I want it to be redirected to the same tabbedpanel page after submission. I am using struts2 framework to configure results of form submission. However, I couldn't redirect it to the nested tabbed panel. Instead, it redirects to a separate page without the tabbed panel. Here is my main tabbed panel in main.jsp:

```
<s:url var="remoteurl" action="nestedtab"/>
<sj:tabbedpanel id="remotetab">
    <sj:tab id="tab1">
    <sj:tab id="tab2">
    <sj:tab id="tab3" href="remoteurl">
</sj:tabbedpanel>
```

here is my nested tabbed panel in child.jsp:

```
<sj:tabbedpanel id="localtab">
    <sj:tab id="tab6">
    <sj:tab id="tab7">
</sj:tabbedpanel>
```

Here is my action:

```
<action name="addusers" class="addusersaction">
    <result name="success">child</result>
</action>
```

Comment: Why the action name differed in the configuration?

Comment: sorry...typo error...action name should be nestedtab...